# Notation for length of path in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, notation

What is the notation for the length (number of edges) of a path P in a graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notation is not unique. If you are the writer, you can choose your own.
For example, if $P$ is the name of a path, you could call its length $|P|$, or $\#P$, or $l(P)$, or $\operatorname{length}(P)$. Just define the notation explicitly.